# How to use LIKE in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table called music with some ids:

```
 6983887641 59088763306 116542622632 106436032725763 6750402929 131572223581891 17337462361 56848544614 108089415891178 27659711968 182011613865 8888384363 43780515976 7872609449 38858586087 107901192572009 9028468518 5461947317 11955325695 64075031411 12673567174
```

And i need to do a query on those ids. If a query like this had been done:

```
SELECT username FROM music WHERE music LIKE '%107901192572009 9028468518%'
```

It would return with the username of the one that has these ids in it's music table. Ok. but the problem is if i add ids in different order there is no result. so if i searched for:

```
56848544614 107901192572009 or 5461947317 9028468518
```

They are in the table, but not in the order, and there is no result. What should i do?

Comment: If I were you, I would rather simply create a new table - one music id per row. Move all existing data by split the strings, and then dump the old table. For compatibility, you can make the new and old table resemble each other - as a matter of fact, they can look exactly the same, just the music id shorter and used in a more proper way. This is simply not the right design for a relational db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username FROM music
WHERE music LIKE '%107901192572009%'
  AND music LIKE '%9028468518%'
```

Note that it will be slow. Also note that it can misfire, since an `id` can be a part of another `id`. There is a better way to do this - look up 1-to-n relations. If not, at least consider doing this (to combat the second problem):

```
SELECT username FROM music
WHERE ' ' + music + ' ' LIKE '% 107901192572009 %'
  AND ' ' + music + ' ' LIKE '% 9028468518 %'
```

Comment: Ok, the first resolution worked. And it wasn't slow at all. But i haven't tried the search with a high number of accesses at the same time, so let's see. To solve the problem of misfire i added a '.' (dot) to the start and end of each id in the table, so the search would be: WHERE music LIKE '%.107901192572009.%'. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not want LIKE you want IN

```
 SELECT username FROM music WHERE music IN (6983887641, 59088763306, 116542622632, 106436032725763);
```

Comment: will the IN look for exact match?

Comment: @Erin - yes it will be exact matches.

Comment: @Amadan - I was making a guess that it was a separate unique column.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: It should be, but it isn't. Also, your query asks for username with any of the listed music, while OP wants username with *all* of listed music.

Comment: @Amadan - it was a bad guess against a bad question :-)

Comment: :) [filler, as I just wanted the smiley]